# Android MediaCodec/NdkMediaCodec GLES2 interop

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, h.264, android-mediacodec

we are trying to decode AVC/h264 bitstreams using the new NdkMediaCodec API. While decoding works fine now, we are struggling to the the contents of the decoded 
video frame mapped to GLES2 for rendering.
The API allows passing a ANativeWindow at configuration time, but we want to control scheduling of the video rendering and ultimately just provide N textures which are filled
with the decoded frame data.

All attempts to map the memory returned by getOutputBuffer() to GLES vie eglCreateImageKHR/external image failed. The NdkMediaCodec seems to use libstagefright/OMX internally.
So the output buffers are very likely allocated using gralloc - arent they? Is there a way to get the gralloc handle/GraphicsBuffer to bind the frame to EGL/GLES2?

Since there are lots of pixel formats for the media frame without any further documentation on their memory layout, it's hard to use NdkMediaCodec robustly.

Thanks alot for any hints!

Answer (score 2):

For general `MediaCodec` in java, create a `SurfaceTexture` for the GL ES texture you want to have the data in, then create a `Surface` out of this `SurfaceTexture`, and use this as target for the `MediaCodec` decoder. See http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ (e.g. EncodeDecodeTest) for an example on doing this.

The `SurfaceTexture` and `Surface` classes aren't available directly in the NDK right now (as far as I know), though, so you'll need to call these via JNI. Then you can create an `ANativeWindow` from the `Surface` using `ANativeWindow_fromSurface`.

You're right that the output buffers are gralloc buffers, but since there's public APIs for doing this it's safer to rely on those than trying to take shortcuts.

Comment: The Ndk Api just takes a single ANativeWindow at config time. What i need is a way to decode each new frame into a different (well N textures in a ringbuffer) texture. Ideal solution - even if it means using private apis - would be a way to get a gralloc handle for ptr returned by get output buffer.

Comment: Do you explicitly need to have access to more than one of the decoded frames at once, or is it enough to have exact control over which of the frames you're using? When using `SurfaceTexture`, you get a callback when a new frame is available, then you can at your own discretion call `updateTexImage()` to swap this new frame into the texture (and call `getTimestamp()` to know which frame this is). So you can have exact control over which frames are used when and where, but you can only use one at a time and only sequentially.

Comment: Yes, i need more than one frame. HW decoding on our other supported platforms (iOS,Intel MFX) works this way. As far as i understood,the texture is not immediately available to GLES2 when calling updateTexImage, isnt it? The video scheduler computes the current render latency for streamed video and determines the display timestamp. Therfor it's crucial the frame is available at that time.
Is it possible to allocated storage for N frames in a single SurfaceTexture and change the GL tex obj binding after storing a frame?

Comment: Internally, the `SurfaceTexture` actually contains multiple buffers (there's a flag if one would want to explicitly disable this); once you've got the callback saying that there's a new frame available, it should be available for use immediately once you call `updateTexImage`. The only caveat is that you don't know the timestamp of the next frame available until you've called `updateTexImage`.

Comment: I see, thanks. So one solution would be to attach new GL Obj-Tex IDs to the SurfaceTexture and hope the internal buffer is sufficiently large or maybe forget the NdkMediaCodec API and just go directly with OMX (or use libstagefright directly). Somehow Android/NDK is a real nightmare - at least for our use cases :(

Comment: Checked the Android Frameworks-Base code, detach also deletes the GL texture. So there's no way to use multiple textures with SurfaceTexture.